# Using vba code to sort multiple tables based on the same column

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I need vba code to help me sort multiple tables in the same sheet without merging them into one table. I have a range of data, from B14:V18, another from B21:V39, and another from B42:V108. I need to sort the data based on the values in column L. However, it needs to be dynamic, because the number of rows in each table could change on any given day. Using the normal sort function in excel just merges all of the data into one table, not keeping them seperate.

The columns will always be B:V, but the rows will be changing. As well, the next table will always be located 3 rows below the last cell of the previous one.

Comment: @SkipIntro is right, but I couldn't resist.

Comment: @DougGlancy Give a man a fish, etc... :o)

Comment: @SkipIntro, it's true, but I wanted to know how to do it, so selfishly took the fish for my own.

Comment: I need to sort the info in column L from biggest to smallest for each table, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this thread is dead but wanted to provide a likely solution to the OP's problem. I used Doug's macro and encountered the same problem the OP did. I simply added `.SortFields.Clear` before the `.SortFields.Add` line, which then caused the macro to run correctly. See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855793/macro-to-sort-multiple-tables-on-two-criteria/26880922#26880922) for my code using two sort criteria.

```
Sub SortTables()
Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
    With lo.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=lo.ListColumns("test2").Range, Order:=xlAscending
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
Next lo
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This will sort all the tables on the active worksheet by a column named "test3". It should work no matter how the tables are situated on the sheet:

```
Sub SortTables()
Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
    With lo.Sort
        .SortFields.Add Key:=lo.ListColumns("test2").Range, Order:=xlAscending
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
Next lo
End Sub
```

Tested in Excel 2010

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for some reason. Do I need to have a certain cell selected? I literally copied that code into excel and changed "test 2" to "Upside", which is the word in my L1. Would this make sense?

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood. Are these three actual Tables, or just areas on a sheet?

Comment: And is your version Excel 2007 or later? If so, it should work as you describe, sorting each table by the column with a header of "Upside."