# Macro to sort multiple tables on two criteria

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I have tried in vain to get the below macro to run correctly. The end goal is a macro that will sort multiple tables (on a single worksheet) based on two criteria, and which will also work on whatever worksheet is active. I can make a macro with exact table references, but seek something more agile to avoid having a macro for each worksheet.

The bulk of my code draws from Doug Glancy's recommendation in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837547/using-a-macro-to-sort-multiple-tables-based-on-the-same-column), but it doesn't run properly (as the original poster noted before the thread died). The macro runs without errors but doesn't actually sort any of the data.

I think the broken portion is the `Key:=lo.ListColumns("Name of table column").Range` part. I am not familiar enough with that syntax to troubleshoot it.

I appreciate any suggestions or alternatives! Also, let me know if my requirements are unclear at all.

```
Sub CustomSort()
Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
    With lo.Sort
        .SortFields.Add Key:=lo.ListColumns("Status").Range, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=lo.ListColumns("Inventory Number").Range, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
Next lo
End Sub
```

Comment: After brief testing it seems to work fine - provided no filters are currently applied. You could add Cells.AutoFilter to automatically remove the filters. Could you elaborate on the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to TomDillinger for prompting me to take a closer look at the macro's behavior. I realized the macro was sorting some of the time, although rarely correctly. I simply added `.SortFields.Clear` before the `.SortFields.Add` lines, which clears any existing sorting for a fresh start so to speak for the sort commands in the macro. Here is the fully functioning macro:

```
Sub CustomSort()
Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
    With lo.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=lo.ListColumns("Status").Range, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=lo.ListColumns("Inventory Number").Range, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
Next lo
End Sub
```